# Looking for advanced poker tutorial strategies

Tags: betting-strategy

I have been playing poker for a while and I want to advance to a higher level and understand different strategies for the games. Do you know some good video tutorial or resources about how to advanced my play? Please share.

Thanks

Comment: try in youtube gripsed or bank poker.

Comment: Just to note, this is one of those questions where it will usually be outside the boundaries of the type of Q's that fit best. However, there are some useful answers here already so i'll leave it open ;) For future reference, please take a look at [this part of the help section](http://poker.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to get a more detailed explanation of what the site is aiming to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of resources on Internet nowadays.

- **[Pokerschoolonline](https://www.pokerschoolonline.com/courses)** courses
- **[Pokerstrategy](http://www.pokerstrategy.com/strategy/)** courses (left column)
- **[Deucescracked](https://www.deucescracked.com/videos)** videos
- **[Thepokerbank](http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/)** strategy
- **[Thepokerbank](http://www.thepokerbank.com/videos/splitsuit/)** videos by 'SplitSuit'
- **[Cardschat](https://www.cardschat.com/poker-strategy.php)** strategy
- **[Two plus Two forums](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com)**, although you'll 
  have a hard time navigating
- **[Two plus Two forums twitch streaming](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/244/twitch-watch-discuss-live-online-poker/)**, many pros playing live (right column)
- **[Youtube](http://youtube.com)**, anything you type, you find

There are way more of course which i'm not aware

Comment: ...Other than this site ;)

Comment: @Toby Booth, of course ;) I was thinking to add it but i tend not when OP used this site to ask 8)

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge amount of resources out there. I'd recommend joining a poker forum like [2+2](http://www.twoplustwo.com/), they have subforums for nearly everything you could want to learn or talk about. [PokerNews](http://www.pokernews.com/) also have a strategy section that is updated daily.

As for videos, look up a guy called Jason Sommerville, you can find him on youtube and he also streams daily on twitch. He is good because he explains every hand while playing through them. [School of Cards](https://www.youtube.com/user/SchoolofCards) also has some nice videos.

Maybe look at picking up some poker books, even the old ones are a great foundation to learning the game, such as Harrington on Hold'em.